# Generate .tar.gz file in java

Tags: java

I generated **.tar.gz** file in java.

When I tried to open that,I m getting exception as "`Unable to read header of that file`" and it asks for some over writing also.

It is also throwing error as

> cannot open file:it does not appear to be a valid archive.
>   My code is as follows

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class Tarzlatest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file =new File(path);

        String gzipFile = path;
        String newFile = path ;

        compressGzipFile(file, gzipFile);

       decompressGzipFile(gzipFile, newFile);

    }

    private static void decompressGzipFile(String gzipFile, String newFile) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(gzipFile);
            GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while((len = gis.read(buffer)) != -1){
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            //close resources
            fos.close();
            gis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void compressGzipFile(File dir, String gzipFile) {
        try {
            File[] flist = dir.listFiles();  
            for(int i=0; i<flist.length; i++)  
            { 
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(flist[i]);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(gzipFile);
            GZIPOutputStream gzipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while((len=fis.read(buffer)) != -1){
                gzipOS.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            //close resources
            gzipOS.close();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: And what is "open that"? What with?

Comment: how did you generate archived file?

Comment: What? How? Why? When? Where?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you generated your **.tar.gz** incorrectly. Simple as that.